# How to display result of a WCF service through a client

Tags: c#, ajax, wcf

I've been following a Microsoft tutorial on setting up AJAX-enabled WCF services and accessing them with a client. However, despite following the tutorial exactly, the result will not display as it is supposed to.

I've followed every step from the following [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/create-an-ajax-wcf-asp-net-client). This may be useful if you wish to retrace my work. I'm working in Visual Studio 2019, and below I have pasted the code for both the WCF service and the web form.

```
//WCF service file defining the operation
namespace SandwichServices
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class CostService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        public double CostOfSandwiches(int quantity)
        {
            return 1.25 * quantity;
        }
    }
}
```

```
//.aspx file for the web form
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="SandwichServices.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function Calculate() {
            CostService.CostOfSandwiches(3, onSuccess);
        }

        function onSuccess(result) {
            var myres = $get("additionResult");
            myres.innerHTML = result;
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
        </div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
            <Services>
                <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/CostService.svc" />
            </Services>
        </asp:ScriptManager>

        <input type="button" value="Price of 3 sandwiches" onclick="Calculate()" />
        <br />
        <span id="additionResult">
        <br />
        </span>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When debugging, the page generates the button properly, but clicking the button should display the result of 3.75. Instead, no result is displayed. Viewing the page source and examining the console reveals the following error upon clicking the button: "SCRIPT5009: 'CostService' is not defined". Any help in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try this : document.getElementById("additionResult"); instead of $get("additionResult");

Comment: I went ahead and tried this, there was no change when I debugged.

Comment: Check your browser debugger. See if there is an error in your javascript.

Comment: Yes as @BlueEyedBehemoth suggested, the best way to find out is to debug your code. Try this tutorial to help you : https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/

Comment: It looks like the issue is with the Calculate function- as previously mentioned, the error involved is "CostService is not defined". Unfortunately I can't seem to find any way to resolve this.

Comment: You have a CostService.svc file and an CostService.svc.cs file, right? And in the CostService.,svc there is a type declaration. Does it match with what is in your .cs file? If you visit http://localhost:[what ever port it is running on]/CostService.svc what does it say?

Comment: @rene Visiting it in localhost returns a screen stating "metadata publishing for this service is currently disabled" and provides a list of steps to enable it. I will give this a try, hopefully it can fix things.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure there is a proper **System.servicemodel** section in the configuration file(web.config) when adding the CostService.svc item to the project.

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WebApplication1.CostServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
      multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="WebApplication1.CostService">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="WebApplication1.CostServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior"
          binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WebApplication1.CostService" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Please use practical assembly/namespace to replace the above property. On my side, I created a **WebApplicaiton1** project, and the default namespace is **WebApplicaiton1**. Besides, both the **CostService.svc** and the **WebForm3.aspx** are in the root directory of the project.
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.
**Updated.**
Recently, I found this issue is a bug. it dues to extensionless URL handlers in IIS which results in the web service fail to recognize.
https://support.microsoft.com/zh-cn/help/2520479/web-services-may-fail-on-microsoft-internet-information-services-iis-7
Also, Here is a workaround. we replace the relative service address with the completed service address(based on the hosting environment).

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        <Services>
            <asp:ServiceReference Path="http://localhost:56697/Content/CostService.svc" />
        </Services>
    </asp:ScriptManager>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however I still encounter 'CostService is not defined' in the browser debugger despite implementing your solution. Is there something else I can try?

Comment: Would you mind telling me more details related to OS version, the target framework of the project, the type of the project template, the browser version used to debug?

Comment: OS: Microsoft Windows 10 Pro Verrsion 10.0.18362
Target framework: .NET Framework 4.7.2 
Project template: empty ASP.Net web application
Debugging tool: IIS Express (Microsoft Edge)

Comment: Bro, I could not find where the problem lies. The same code works well on my side. The running environment is basically the same. I am sorry for that. I suggest you run your code on the other computer.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/zh-cn/help/2520479/web-services-may-fail-on-microsoft-internet-information-services-iis-7